# How to listen to COM events from Office applications that were started independently?

Tags: c++, events, com, ms-office

**What I want to do:**

Write an application that listens to Office events.  I want to listen to events from any instance opened on the machine.  E.g. if I'm listening to BeforeDocumentSave in Word, then I want my sink for this method to be activated whenever any instance of Word on the host saves a document.

Another requirement is that I'm writing in C++ without MFC or ATL.

**What I've done:**

I've written a program that's supposed to listen to Word events.  See the code below.

**The problem:**

It doesn't work - the event handlers are never entered, although I open a word application and do the actions that should trigger the events.

I have some specific questions, and of course any other input would be very welcome!

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to listen to events from an application that wasn't started by me?  In all the examples I found, the listening application starts the office application it wants to listen to.
2. In a microsoft howto (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183599/EN-US/) I found the following comment:

> However, most events, such as
>   Microsoft Excel's Workbook events, do
>   not start with DISPID 1. In such
>   cases, you must explicitly modify the
>   dispatch map in MyEventSink.cpp to
>   match the DISPIDs with the correct
>   methods.

How do I modify the dispatch map?

1. For now I've defined only Startup, Quit and DocumentChange, which take no arguments.  The methods I really need do take arguments, specifically one of type Document.  How do I define parameters of this type if I'm not using MFC?

**Code:**

Here's the header file for my project, followed by the C file:

```
#ifndef _OFFICEEVENTHANDLER_H_
#define _OFFICEEVENTHANDLER_H_

// 000209FE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
static const GUID IID_IApplicationEvents2 =  
{0x000209FE,0x0000,0x0000, {0xC0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x46}};

struct IApplicationEvents2 : public IDispatch // Pretty much copied from typelib
{
/*
 * IDispatch methods
 */
STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObj) = 0; 
STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()  = 0;  
STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release() = 0;

STDMETHODIMP GetTypeInfoCount(UINT *iTInfo) = 0;
STDMETHODIMP GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo **ppTInfo) = 0;
STDMETHODIMP GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, OLECHAR **rgszNames, 
                              UINT cNames,  LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId) = 0;
STDMETHODIMP Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid,
                              WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pDispParams,
                              VARIANT* pVarResult, EXCEPINFO* pExcepInfo,
                              UINT* puArgErr) = 0;

/*
 * IApplicationEvents2 methods
 */
STDMETHODIMP Startup();
STDMETHODIMP Quit();
STDMETHODIMP DocumentChange();
};


class COfficeEventHandler : IApplicationEvents2
{

public:
DWORD                        m_dwEventCookie;

COfficeEventHandler
(
) :
m_cRef(1),
m_dwEventCookie(0)
{
}

STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)()
{
InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);

return m_cRef;  
}

STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)()
{
InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);

if (m_cRef == 0)
{
    delete this;
    return 0;
}

return m_cRef;
}

STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObj)
{
 if (riid == IID_IUnknown){
    *ppvObj = static_cast<IApplicationEvents2*>(this);
}

else if (riid == IID_IApplicationEvents2){
    *ppvObj = static_cast<IApplicationEvents2*>(this);
}
else if (riid == IID_IDispatch){
    *ppvObj = static_cast<IApplicationEvents2*>(this);
}

else
{
    char clsidStr[256];
    WCHAR wClsidStr[256];
    char txt[512];

    StringFromGUID2(riid, (LPOLESTR)&wClsidStr, 256);

    // Convert down to ANSI
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wClsidStr, -1, clsidStr, 256, NULL, NULL);

    sprintf_s(txt, 512, "riid is : %s: Unsupported Interface", clsidStr);

    *ppvObj = NULL;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

static_cast<IUnknown*>(*ppvObj)->AddRef();

return S_OK;
}

STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfoCount)(UINT* pctinfo)
{
return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfo)(UINT itinfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo** pptinfo)
{
return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHOD(GetIDsOfNames)(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR* rgszNames, UINT cNames,
       LCID lcid, DISPID* rgdispid)
{
return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHOD(Invoke)(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid,
       LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult,
       EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
{
return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// IApplicationEvents2 methods
void Startup();
void Quit();
void DocumentChange();


protected:
LONG                        m_cRef;
};

#endif // _OFFICEEVENTHANDLER_H_
```

The C file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "OfficeEventHandler.h"
#include "OCIdl.h"



int main()
{
CLSID clsid;                   // CLSID of automation object 
HRESULT hr; 
LPUNKNOWN punk = NULL;         // IUnknown of automation object 
LPDISPATCH pdisp = NULL;       // IDispatch of automation object 
IConnectionPointContainer *pConnPntCont;
IConnectionPoint *pConnPoint;
IUnknown *iu;
IID id;  
COfficeEventHandler *officeEventHandler = new COfficeEventHandler;

CoInitialize(NULL);

hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("Word.Application"), &clsid); 

hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER,  
                      IID_IUnknown, (void FAR* FAR*)&punk); 

hr = punk->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void FAR* FAR*)&pConnPntCont); 

// IID for ApplicationEvents2 
hr = IIDFromString(L"{000209FE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}",&id);

hr = pConnPntCont->FindConnectionPoint( id, &pConnPoint );

hr = officeEventHandler->QueryInterface( IID_IUnknown, (void FAR* FAR*)&iu);

hr = pConnPoint->Advise( iu, &officeEventHandler->m_dwEventCookie );

Sleep( 360000 );

hr = pConnPoint->Unadvise( officeEventHandler->m_dwEventCookie );
if (punk) punk->Release(); 
if (pdisp) pdisp->Release(); 

CoUninitialize();

return hr; 
}

// IApplicationEvents2 methods
void COfficeEventHandler::Startup()
{
printf( "In Startup\n" );
}

void COfficeEventHandler::Quit()
{
printf( "In Quit\n" );
}

void COfficeEventHandler::DocumentChange()
{
printf( "In DocumentChnage\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your number one problem  is you don't run the message loop in the main thread and [that causes the events to never reach your sink object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136885). Calls form the COM server to your sink object are dispatched using Windows messages, so you have to run the message loop instead of simply calling `Sleep()` so that the incoming events are eventually dispatched to the sink object.

Answer (score 3):

I found two problems in the code I gave here:

1. As sharptooth pointed out, Sleep is wrong here. It even causes the application I listen to to hang, or sleep.  I put in a message loop as sharptooth suggested.
2. I hadn't implemented 'Invoke'.  I thought that if I implemented the event methods themselves, they would be called by the application, but this is not the case.  I had to implement invoke and make it switch on the dispid and call the different event methods.  I found the dispid in the typelib.  Looking at a method in the OLE viewer, I used the 'id' which apparently is the dispid.

Following is a corrected .cpp file.  In the .h file the only correction is to change Invoke into a declaration instead of an implementation.

Two notes on the code:

1. I constructed it out of various examples I found, so you may find names or comments that seem irrelevant because they were taken from elsewhere.
2. To get the COM object I used either `GetActiveObject` or `CoCreateInstance`. The former works only if the event firing application is already running.  The latter creates an invisible instance of it.  For Word this worked well, possibly because if I open another Word instance its part of the same process.  I haven't checked yet what happens if I open a new process, if the events would still be triggered.

Hope this helps!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "OfficeEventHandler.h"
#include "OCIdl.h"



int main()
{
    CLSID clsid;                   // CLSID of automation object 
    HRESULT hr; 
    LPUNKNOWN punk = NULL;         // IUnknown of automation object 
    LPDISPATCH pdisp = NULL;       // IDispatch of automation object 
    IConnectionPointContainer *pConnPntCont;
    IConnectionPoint *pConnPoint;
    IUnknown *iu;
    IID id;  
    COfficeEventHandler *officeEventHandler = new COfficeEventHandler;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("Word.Application"), &clsid); 

 /*  hr = GetActiveObject( clsid, NULL, &punk );
 */  hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER,  
                          IID_IUnknown, (void FAR* FAR*)&punk); 

    hr = punk->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void FAR* FAR*)&pConnPntCont); 

    // IID for ApplicationEvents2 
    hr = IIDFromString(L"{000209FE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}",&id);

    hr = pConnPntCont->FindConnectionPoint( id, &pConnPoint );

    hr = officeEventHandler->QueryInterface( IID_IUnknown, (void FAR* FAR*)&iu);

    hr = pConnPoint->Advise( iu, &officeEventHandler->m_dwEventCookie );

    MSG   msg;
    BOOL  bRet;

    while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0 )
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }

        if( msg.message == WM_QUERYENDSESSION || msg.message == WM_QUIT || msg.message == WM_DESTROY )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    hr = pConnPoint->Unadvise( officeEventHandler->m_dwEventCookie );
    if (punk) punk->Release(); 
    if (pdisp) pdisp->Release(); 

    CoUninitialize();

    return hr; 
}

    // IApplicationEvents2 methods
void COfficeEventHandler::Startup()
{
    printf( "In Startup\n" );
}

void COfficeEventHandler::Quit()
{
    printf( "In Quit\n" );
}

void COfficeEventHandler::DocumentChange()
{
    printf( "In DocumentChnage\n" );
}

STDMETHODIMP COfficeEventHandler::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid,
           LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult,
           EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
{
    //Validate arguments
    if ((riid != IID_NULL))
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;  // Initialize

    /* To see what Word sends as dispid values */
    static char myBuf[80];
    memset( &myBuf, '\0', 80 );
    sprintf_s( (char*)&myBuf, 80, " Dispid: %d :", dispIdMember );

    switch(dispIdMember){
    case 0x01:    // Startup
        Startup();
    break;
    case 0x02:    // Quit
        Quit();
    break;
    case 0x03:    // DocumentChange
        DocumentChange();
    break;
    }

    return S_OK;
 }
```

Comment: When I am trying to do use the same code with excel, I am getting a runtime error that says pConnPoint is nullptr. I checked hr, hr is 0 i.e. S_OK! What are the changes to be made for excel?